# Highstock xAxis datetime pointer line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this Highstock config:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
chart: {
    // type: 'spline',
    type: 'column',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    zoomType: 'x',
},
rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false,
},
title: {
    text: "Title"
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
        month: '%e. %b',
        year: '%b'
    },
    labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 3,
        y: -3,
    },
    // TODO: fix that f*****g timezone
    min: new Date('01/01/2018').getTime() + 7200000,
    max: new Date('10/01/2018').getTime() + 7200000,
    crosshair: true,
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000 * 24,
},

yAxis: [
    {
        opposite: false,
        title: {
            text: "Energy",
            style: {
                color: '#F2A9A9'
            },
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            format: '{value:.,0f}',
            style: {
                color: '#F2A9A9'
            },
        },
    },
],

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshair: true
},
legend: {
    enabled: true,
},
series: [{"color": "#F2A9A9", "data": [{"y": 210.0, "x": 1514771237000}, {"y": 120.0, "x": 1515052404000}, {"y": 90.0, "x": 1515221072000}, {"y": 0.0, "x": 1515311127000}], "name": "Energy (MWh)"}, {"color": "deepskyblue", "data": [{"y": 0.0, "x": 1514788069000}, {"y": 0.0, "x": 1514868337000}, {"y": 0.0, "x": 1515074982000}], "name": "Energy (MW)"}, {"color": "#90ed7d", "data": [{"y": 0.0, "x": 1514788069000}, {"y": 0.0, "x": 1514868337000}, {"y": 0.0, "x": 1515074982000}], "name": "Volume"}]
});
```

The problem is that the graph hover is not on the middle of the column (see the image). I do not understand why the mouse hover line over a column value is not on the middle of the column. It is a little bit on the right of the column.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of3rT.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default **grouping** mechanism is enabled in Highstock. It causes that every x value has space reserved for one column from each series (3 in this case). Even though all points form the second and the third series have 0 as y value, Highcharts behaves as if they're visible.

Hide the second and the third series to see the columns from the first series centered.

To have that effect without hiding any series just disable grouping:

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2hLpgn0t/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping